# Експорт данных sql developer

Tags: oracle

Делаю дамп всей БД через sql developer

> In SQL Developer, from the top menu choose **Tools > Data Export**

При експорте получаю ошибку

> File C:\Users\xxx\export.sql was not opened because it exceeds the maximum automatic open size

Я так понимаю что не все данные перенеслись в файл . 
Как сделать полный дамп без ошибок?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, данные перенеслись все, но sql developer решил не открывать результат экспорта в редакторе, т.к. файл получился слишком большой.

Answer (score 1):

У SQL Developer есть ограничение на размер файла экспорта, выгружаемого таким образом. В качестве обходного пути могу посоветовать выгружать не как insert выражения, а скажем, как csv. Сэкономите на синтаксисе.